# Umbraco 7. Multinode tree picker skip nodes that no longer exist

Tags: c#, umbraco7

In Umbraco 7, we have a Mulitnode tree picker on a node.  We choose a different node with the MNTP. We then delete the picked node out of the Umbraco tree, but NOT out of the MNTP on the original node.  In C# how would we loop through the MNTP and check to see if the chosen node in the MNTP exists anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still can get the node by id, you can check if the Name property is null

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Name)
```

It's not pretty but should work